# Create a Modal popup with buttons

Tags: 8, ajax

I am having issues opening a modal with buttons using `OpenModalDialogCommand`.
It says in the docs of that command, that it can take as it's 3rd param any Jquery UI option (from http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) and it works well, for width/height/class, but anything more advanced i hit a wall. I am trying to make a button but can't figure it out.

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$options = [
    'width' => '800',
    'height' => '300',
    'dialogClass' => 'no-close',
    'buttons' => [
      'text' => 'Proceed',
      'click' => 'function() {alert();}'
    ]
];

$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('Title', 'Body', $options));
return $response;
```

This returns a modal successfully, width is ok, height is ok, class is ok, but there is not button, i tried 3/4 variations of it with no luck.

~p.s. i know i can make a simple form with one button, and return that in the modal, but there has got to be a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out.

```
$options = [
    'dialogClass' => 'my-form',
    'buttons' => [
        'button1' => [
            'text' => 'Proceed',
            'id' => 'onClickDoSomething',
        ]
    ]
];
```

And then in the `.js` file just write a function which fires when clickcing on a selector with the id `onClickDoSomething` voila, it's working.